# Error with cast digits to String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, xcode, casting

I am beginner in Swift and Xcode and still don't know few basic things.

When I parse data from JSON always meet with digits which have to cast to String. All digits turn on nil. Why?

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var titlenews = ""
var title_segue = ""
var id_segue = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsfeedCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCell
    cell.newsfeed_title.text = self.news?[indexPath.item].headline
    cell.newsfeed_topic.text = self.news?[indexPath.item].topic
    cell.newsfeed_time.text = timetime(from: (self.news?[indexPath.item].time)!)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Launch tableview in SecondView")
    title_segue = (self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!
    id_segue = (self.news?[indexPath.item].id)!
    print(("tableView: "+(self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!))
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "newsbodysegue", sender: self)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.news!.count
} //number of rows

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var news: [Newsfeed]? = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJSON()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getJSON(){

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://sportarena.com/wp-api/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=25")!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        self.news = [Newsfeed]()
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSArray

            for arrayX in json as! [[String: Any]] {
               let NF = Newsfeed()

                let categories0 = arrayX["categories"] as? NSArray
                let title0 = arrayX["title"] as? [String: Any]

                if let ID = arrayX["id"],
                    let date = arrayX["date"],
                    let status = arrayX["status"],
                    let title = title0!["rendered"],
                    let categories = categories0?[0] {
                        NF.headline = title as? String
                        NF.topic = status as? String
                        print (ID)
                        NF.id = ID as? String
                        NF.time = date as? String
                }
                self.news?.append(NF)
             }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "newsbodysegue") {
        let NewsBodyController = segue.destination as! NewsBody
        NewsBodyController.labeltext = id_segue
    }
}

}
```

Line "id_segue = (self.news?[indexPath.item].id)!" give error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Why nil if print (ID) show me right digits which parsed from JSON?

What I need to change? Please help me.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON you’re parsing to get the ID?

Comment: Is there any way that ID from json is actually an Int and not String? And when you print it is shown, but when you try to cast it as? String, it fails to do so and leaves nil there?

Comment: Your topic implies the answer. **Digits are not string**. Please **read** the JSON. The value for key `id` is a number (`Int`) not a string. All values in double quotes are strings. And you are using too many question and exclamation marks. For example never declare a data source array as optional. @PeteMorris Please paste the given URL into a browser to see the JSON

Comment: @inokey is correct. The id properties in your JSON are type Int. Your cast to a String is failing and therefore nil is being stored in NF.id. If you want it to be a String, try String interpolation instead: NF.id = “\\(ID)”.

Comment: @PeteMorris yeah, thank you. I was need specified to this way.